# What is process.env.UNIVERSAL in this node.js code

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm working through a react with node tutorial and i have some code that looks like this:

```
if(process.env.UNIVERSAL){

  markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(...)

  .
  .
  .
}
```

I understand that process.env stores environment variables but i'm not sure what `UNIVERSAL` is or where it comes from. I tried to print it out in this code:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';
server.listen(port, err => {
 if (err) {
  return console.error(err);
 }
console.info(process.env.UNIVERSAL + ' test');
console.info(`Server running on http://localhost:${port} [${env}]`);
});
```

But it comes out undefined. Any idea what `process.env.UNIVERSAL` is?

Comment: It's an environment variable. You pass it to a node script at the command line with `UNIVERSAL=something node my_application.js`

Comment: but i don't pass it in a node script or on the command line anywhere and i'm still able to view my web application when the server loads

Comment: Search your source code for that string

Comment: This does not come with default nodejs. I think you have installed packages like https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-universal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While running a node.js code, you can specify the environment variables. Say for example you have  your node.js server in `app.js` file. You can specify the env parameters while running like

```
NODE_ENV=development node app.js
```

for a `UNIX` environment

or

```
SET NODE_ENV=development & node app.js
```

for `Windows environment`

and then you can access it in your scripts with `process.env.NODE_ENV`

Similarly you can specify the environment `UNIVERSAL` while running the script

like

```
UNIVERSAL=test node app.js
```

Since you are not specifying anything, you get its value is `undefined` in the script